# 'I hope this helps' vs. 'I hope this will help'

Tags: grammar, present-tense, future-tense

An English expert at the end of his answer to a question, which is published online, wrote

> I hope this helps.

Would the meaning be (slightly) different if he had written "I hope this will help" instead?

Comment: The meaning won't be different, but the specific phrasing "I hope this helps" is so common that [HTH](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=HTH) is a standard abbreviation for "[I] Hope This Helps" on the internet.